# How to take button icon from data while using v-for

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I have a data like this:

```
subclasses: [
        {
          title: "Ancestral Guardian",
          value: 1,
          icon:"mdi-book"
        },
        {
          title: "Battlerager",
          value: 2,
          icon:"mdi-school"
        },
```

I want to use the icon value for buttons that are generated in for loop

I tried to do this but it didn't work:

```
                <v-col v-for="sub in subclasses" :key="sub.sub">
                  <div class="d-flex justify-center">
                    <v-btn               
                    @click="goTo(sub.title)"
                    class=" pa-3 mb-2 "
                    color="rgb(54, 61, 68)"
                    icon={{sub.icon}}
                    >
                  </v-btn>
                  </div>
                    <p class="text-center">{{ sub.title }}</p>
                </v-col>
```

Comment: When using icon on button, use ```append-icon``` or ```prepend-icon``` then bind it so you can code like this ```:append-icon="sub.icon"```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I post in the comment, you can use `append-icon` and `prepend-icon` then bind it.

But other way is to add `v-icon` inside the `v-btn` tag.

[Demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)